# How to select a constructor by ExplicitArguments type in StructureMap?

Tags: c#, structuremap

I have the class `Foo` with 3 constructors where each of them has 2 parameters.

```
public class Foo
{
    public string Location;

    public Foo(IContainer container, DefaultData data)
    {
        Location = "DefaultData";
    }

    public Foo(IContainer container, DbData data)
    {
        Location = "DbData";
    }

    public Foo(IContainer container, NetworkData data)
    {
        Location = "NetworkData";
    }
}

public class DefaultData
{
}

public class DbData
{
}

public class NetworkData
{
}
```

Now if I want to get an instance

```
var container = new Container();

ExplicitArguments args = new ExplicitArguments();
args.Set(new NetworkData(new decimal(1.3D), 'f'));

var instance = container.GetInstance<Foo>(args);
```

I'm always getting the following exception:

```
Unable to create a build plan for concrete type TestConsole.DefaultData
new DefaultData(String s, Int32 i)
  ┣ String s = Required primitive dependency is not explicitly defined
  ┗ Int32 i = Required primitive dependency is not explicitly defined
1.) Attempting to create a BuildPlan for Instance of TestConsole.DefaultData -- TestConsole.DefaultData
2.) new Foo(*Default of IContainer*, *Default of DefaultData*)
3.) TestConsole.Foo
4.) Instance of TestConsole.Foo
5.) Container.GetInstance<TestConsole.Foo>({TestConsole.NetworkData=TestConsole.NetworkData})
```

I also tried to solve my problem with a custom `IConstructor` selector, but I don't receive the supplied parameter (types) and cannot decide which constructor I should use then.

---

I want to achieve that the constructor is automatically selected by the passed `ExplicitArguments`.

Comment: I'm not familiar with structuremap but their documentation says that you could [explicitly select a constructor](http://structuremap.github.io/registration/constructor-selection/) with `.SelectConstructor(() => new Foo(null)); // invoke the correct ctor here`

Comment: There you define the (one and only one) specific constructor before you create an instance. But I need to define 3 constructors.